# org.apache.poi create excel workbook with date cells

Tags: java, excel, apache, date, apache-poi

I have date in java in this format: "2014.01.31 14:24:28". I would like to put it into excel using apache poi library with cell format type: "date".
How can I achive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells): Change the date in your desired format and use that.

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
//Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

// Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

// Create a cell and put a date value in it.  The first cell is not styled
// as a date.
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(new Date());

// we style the second cell as a date (and time).  It is important to
// create a new cell style from the workbook otherwise you can end up
// modifying the built in style and effecting not only this cell but other cells.
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(
    createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"));
cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(new Date());
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

//you can also set date as java.util.Calendar
cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue(Calendar.getInstance());
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
HSSFCell myCell;
myCell.setCellValue(dateFormat.format("2014.01.31 14:24:28"));`